# Is there a way to manually handle exception from variable validation in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

Hey I'm using FastAPI for a project of my own and it's my first time using it. I wonder if there is a way for me to manually handle the exception when the data I'm receiving does not match the type I'm waiting for.

Here's an example :

```
async def create_user(password: str = Form("password"), username: str = Form("username"), email: str = Form("email"), pseudo: str = Form("pseudo")):
    conn.execute(user.insert().values(
        username=username,
        email=email,
        password=password,
        pseudo=pseudo
    ))
    return conn.execute(user.select()).fetchall()
```

I would like to return a 400 error and a personnal message when this route receive a username that is an int for example. Technically not supposed to but I want to handle it myself anyway, it could be usefull for other error handling situations.

I haven't found it on my research yet and that's why I'm asking here. Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastAPI is built with Pydantic for these sort of validations. There are two ways I can think of doing this:

- (a) Use `typing.Any` to accept any input, and validate the input yourself in the function- raising any `HTTPException` as needed.

  ```
  from typing import Any
  from fastapi import HTTPException

  # @app. ....
  async def create_user(password: str = Form("password"), username: Any = Form("username"), email: str = Form("email"), pseudo: str = Form("pseudo")):

      if not isinstance(username, str) or (isistance(username, str) and username.isdigit()):
          raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Must be a string.") 

      conn.execute(user.insert().values(
          username=username,
          email=email,
          password=password,
          pseudo=pseudo
      ))
      return conn.execute(user.select()).fetchall()
  ```
- (b) Take in a `str` input as the default, and check for the things you are looking for.

  ```
  from fastapi import HTTPException

  # @app. ....
  async def create_user(password: str = Form("password"), username: str = Form("username"), email: str = Form("email"), pseudo: str = Form("pseudo")):

      # Assuming you have a proper html form setup in the front-end the expected
      # input to this endpoint will always be a string. If somehow the user sends
      # a request without the form (say with Postman), then Pydantic will be the 
      # one that will catch the error (via 422 error) and not the code below.
      if username.isdigit():
          raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Must be a string.") 

      conn.execute(user.insert().values(
          username=username,
          email=email,
          password=password,
          pseudo=pseudo
      ))
      return conn.execute(user.select()).fetchall()
  ```

Whichever the case, I think it's worth mentioning that the entire point of FastAPI is for automatic validation via Pyndatic. If you plan on doing validation manually for *everything*, you are better off working with something like [Starlette](https://github.com/encode/starlette), which gives you more control of the flow of data at the cost of not having built-in data validators.

Comment: Nice and clear answer, thank you ! What I would like to do is personnalizing error codes ans messages but as you say, I may be not doing it with the right tool. There will not be any Front-end going with this api, that's why I want a personnalized back-end validation.

Comment: In such case, you might be better off not using `Form` and instead using a custom `Pydantic` model to validate your data. This will give you better customization options (see [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/) and [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/)). `Form` is usually used in conjunction with an HTML front-end that is sending form-specific data, and not pure REST-like requests (via `json`).